# Asynchronously updating a ListView

Tags: java, android

I'm dealing with the following api call https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/, the problem is that it seems quite slow and each entry has itself several endpoints. Is it possible to update `ListView` asynchronously while making the `api` calls? I feel that it will probably be something like using the endpoint's next and previous keys and triggering `listener` events that update the `Listview` from the `AsyncTask's doInBackground` or `onProgressUpdate` methods. I'd appreciate any help, I feel that I have the beginning of an idea, but I need help finishing the thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely implement it through AsyncTask but I would rather suggest a solution using RxJava.

You can implement **RxJava Chaining**.

Sharing a code snippet how you can make a chaining call using RxJava.

```
 private void fetchHackerNewsStoriesChaining() {

        StoriesApiInterface storiesApiInterface = HackerNewsApiClient.getStoriesApiInterface();
        storiesApiInterface.getTopStories()
                .flatMapIterable(new Function<JsonArray, Iterable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterable<?> apply(JsonArray jsonArray) throws Exception {
                        Log.d("Count", ""+jsonArray.size());
                        return jsonArray;
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Function<Object, ObservableSource<SingleStoryModelResponse>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<SingleStoryModelResponse> apply(Object newsId) throws Exception {

                        return HackerNewsApiClient.getStoryDetailsApiInterface().getNewsStoryDetail(((JsonElement) newsId).getAsLong())
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<SingleStoryModelResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(SingleStoryModelResponse singleStoryModelResponse) {
                        adapterNewsList.addNewsItem(singleStoryModelResponse);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d("Hacker News", e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: I agree with the use of RxJava but the learning curve of it is very deep. Still, this is I think the best way to do it. RxJava is worth to learn.

Comment: @TentenPonce agree this was just a suggestion aka idea, but yes it can also be implemented using AsyncTask as well.